# Why is libjpeg.so.8 missing from Debian?

Tags: debian, libraries, jpeg

Debian 10, but same issue applies to Debian 11.

Trying to run a certain binary (gaming), I get complaints about libjpeg.so.8 missing.

`apt-file search libjpeg.so.8` gives no results.

However I can see libjpeg62-turbo in the repos.

Looks like libjpeg.so.8 isn't available, even in non-free, even in backports?

Ubuntu seems to have it though!

What's the story here? Why doesn't Debian have libjpeg 8? And more crucially, how can I get it?

If I'm reading this correctly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libjpeg

Looks like version 8 was released 12 years ago?

Shouldn't Debian include both versions of the libs, so you can use either if a program needs either? What am I missing here?

Comment: You could file a bug. That's the way to try to fix things that are broken. If it is not a bug, the maintainers will let you know why. [Other options are available](https://www.debian.org/support) to get support and answers.

Comment: Definitely! I'm happy to file a bug report, but does a library missing from repos count as a bug? I would imagine the Debian devs would simply go "not a bug, wontfix, closed".

Answer (score 5):

Debian used to include `libjpeg8`, but [it was removed in 2017 in favour of `libjpeg9`](https://bugs.debian.org/867047). In practice, the `libjpeg` library in Debian is [`libjpeg62-turbo`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/libjpeg-turbo) — that’s the only `libjpeg` variant provided in Debian 10 and 11 ([the decision is documented in #717076](https://bugs.debian.org/717076)).

The general rule in Debian is to only carry libraries which are necessary for the distribution itself. Trying to provide all libraries potentially needed for any given binary out there is impossible.

However, old packages don’t disappear entirely, and in many cases they can still be used. The last version of `libjpeg8` published in Debian is [available from snapshots](http://snapshot.debian.org/package/libjpeg8/8d1-2/), and can be installed on current Debian releases; you’ll also need [`multiarch-support` from snapshots](http://snapshot.debian.org/package/glibc/2.28-10/#multiarch-support_2.28-10).

You could always file a bug asking for a compatibility package, which is [the approach taken in Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libjpeg8-empty), but I’m not sure how well received such a solution would be in Debian.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but recently I updated my parsec version and noted that it still needs libjpeg8. A simple solution to this problem is the installation libjpeg62-turbo and creation  of a symbolic link:

```
apt-get install apt-get install libjpeg62-turbo
```

After installation is complete, create a symbolic link:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8
```

It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Double necro as the previous suggestion bites back in Debian 12

The simple solution before installing parsec install:

```
https://archive.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libj/libjpeg8/libjpeg8_8b-1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: This worked great for me on Debian trixie. It's also feels like a lot less hacky of a solution than symlinking libjpeg.so.62 as libjpeg.so.8. Thanks for the answer!